Is it true that power series ring is isomorphic to infinite direct product of ring
I am wondering whether it is true that $R[[x]]$ $\cong$ $\Pi_{\alpha \geq 0} R_\alpha$.
To define an isomorphism between them we can choose $f(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...+a_nx^n+...)=(a_0,a_1,...,a_n,...).$
The map is obviously bijective. I think the problem will occur in $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$ because in direct product we get componentwise multiplication while in product of polynomials we get extra term like $(a_0b_1+a_1b_0)x$.

You've more-or-less proved that the bijection you mention is not a homomorphism. Good. But could any other map work? Hint: your direct product ring has many elements $t$ with $t^2=t$ (e.g. $(0,1,0,0,\dots)$). Can you show the power series ring only has two such elements?

(I think the previous comment assumes the notation $R=\mathbb R$, the real numbers, which is not unreasonable.  There can be more idempotents if $R$ is just some ring.)

@ancientmathematician I think this would make a good hint-solution, if you could please take the time to migrate it from comments to solutions.

@rschwieb I am not sure the "level" this is to be answered at, so I got cold feet. If $R$ is the reals then what I sad is OK. But I think I can produce a ring $R$ (and copies $R_n$) such that $R\simeq R[[x]]\simeq\Pi_{n=0}^{\infty}R_n$.  I am not sure what the OP wants.

Is it false for any ring $R$? Perhaps one could construct $R$ itself as an infinite product and/or a power series ring in infinitely many variables.

@not_a_chatbot Exactly.

@ancientmathematician They asked "is it true that..." and since a counterexample exists, the elementary suggestion you made would answer the question.  Asking if such a ring exists that makes it true is another matter..

@not_a_chatbot Is it false for any ring $R$? ...infinitely many variables. Yes, and you don't even need to be that complicated. It doesn't even work for $\mathbb Z$.

I was actually wondering whether examples of $R$ such that $R[[x]] \cong R^{\mathbb{N}}$ exist, using such a construction. It would have to not be an integral domain.

@not_a_chatbot Sorry, at some point I confused you for the OP.  I understand now you're asking that version.
